# Is there a way in AngularJS call function in select?

Tags: angularjs

I need something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="customer in customers">
    <select ng-options="option.Name for option in **getOptions(customer.ID)**"></select>
</div>
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes , as long as the function is synchronous. Using a filter expression in ng-options is also an alternative

```js
const app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function() {  
  this.getNames = () => ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as $ctrl">
  <select ng-model=" $ctrl.selectedName" ng-options="item for item in  $ctrl.getNames()" size=5>
  </select>
   <p ng-if=" $ctrl.selectedName">Selected: {{ $ctrl.selectedName}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I can't work it. My code below.

Comment: There's no `ng-app` or `ng-controller` in your sample

Comment: Sorry. I fixed it. But still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function() {  
  this.getNames = () => ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as $ctrl">
  <select ng-model=" $ctrl.selectedName" ng-options="item for item in  $ctrl.getNames()" size=5>
  </select>
   <p ng-if=" $ctrl.selectedName">Selected: {{ $ctrl.selectedName}}</p>
</div>
```

Thank you for your answer. But I can't work it. My code below.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("MainModule", []);

        app.controller('TestController', function ($scope, $http, $filter) {

            $scope.one = ["Sam", "Samantha", "George"]
            $scope.two = ["Jack", "Sandra", "Bill"]

            $scope.getOptions = function (id) {
                if (id === 1) {
                    return $scope.one;
                }
                else if (id ===2) {
                    return $scope.two;
                }
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="MainModule" ng-controller="TestController>
    <div>
        
        <select ng-options="item for item in TestController.getOptions(1)"></select>
    <select ng-options="item for item in TestController.getOptions(2)"></select>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since you are using $scope and not `controller as` syntax it should just be `"item for item in getOptions(1)"`